# MYSQL query reducing the inner query in conditions

Tags: mysql

I am running into a small problem,

This is a demo query

```
select 
    A.order_id, 
    if(
         A.production_date != '0000-00-00', 
         A.production_date,
         if(
              SOME INNER QUERY != '0000-00-00', 
              SOME INNER QUERY ,
              SOME OTHER INNER QUERY
           )
    ) as production_start_date
from
    orders A
```

So basically, suppose  the `SOME INNER QUERY` is taking 10 seconds to do its calculations, fetching data from 8 different tables, checking past history for same order type etc. and if its result is a date, I fetch that date in first condition. But now it will take 20 seconds as 10 seconds for calculation for if condition, and 10 seconds to re-execute to return the result.

Is there any way I can reduce this?

if any one is interested in looking at actual query http://pastebin.com/zqzbpEei

Comment: +1 because you did NOT include that wall of code in the question.

Comment: My suggestion is to rewrite the "INNER QUERIES" from correlated subqueries (that they are now) to `LEFT` joins in the `FROM` clause of your main query. It will probably improve efficiency for 2 reasons: 1. they will not have to calculated twice and 2. They will not be run once for every row of `orders`.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, but my query is being generated from many functions from different classes, depending upon the parameters. I hope you have seen the full query. I am afraid to do any restructuring of them at this big scale

Comment: I looked into your sql query you have put in http://pastebin.com/zqzbpEei. Horrible. How did u write this query. It will be better if u write a simple stored procedure, use temporary tables instead of writing such a bigger query.

Comment: you are right, but this is the end result of PHP if else conditions. and there are different functions to create different parts of the queries. and the last function is combining all the parts and make a big query... :)

Comment: split all the parts into stored procedures. And in your main query just call all stored procedures. What I see in your query, similar type of calculations are done so many times. You can save them into a temp file and use it in your query. It will be better if you clearly mention what are your tables, give some sample data,and give a sample output data. Then we can suggest, how it can be simplified

Comment: problem is that the sub query is dependent upon the top query, like `Inner.order_id = Outer.order_id`

Comment: it can be simplified. But think in a different way as I mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your query looks like this (sorry, I gave up trying to locate the actual query):

```
IF(
    (SELECT aField FROM aTable WHERE bigCondition) != '0000-00-00',
    SELECT aField FROM aTable WHERE bigCondition,
    SELECT anotherField FROM anotherTable
)
```

You can rewrite it as follows:

```
SELECT IF (
    someField != '0000-00-00',
    someField,
    SELECT anotherField FROM anotherTable
)
FROM aTable WHERE bigCondition
```

This way you compute `bigCondition` only once.

---

This query is quite ugly indeed.

Your major problem seems to be the misuse (and abuse, big time) of the `IF()` construct. It should be reserved to simple conditions and operations. The same applies to logical operators. Do not operate on entire queries. For instance, I see this one bit appears a few times in your query:

```
IF(
    (SELECT v1.weekends FROM vendor v1 WHERE v1.vendor_id = A.vendor_id) IS NULL
       OR (SELECT v1.weekends FROM vendor v1 WHERE v1.vendor_id = A.vendor_id) = '',
    '6', -- by the way, why is this a string?! This is an integer, isn't it?
    (SELECT v1.weekends FROM vendor v1 WHERE v1.vendor_id = A.vendor_id)
)
```

This is Bad. The condition should be moved into the `SELECT` directly. Rewrite it as below:

```
SELECT
    IF (v1.weekends IS NULL OR v1.weekends = '', 6, v1.weekends)
FROM vendor v1 WHERE v1.vendor_id = A.vendor_id
```

That's two `SELECT` saved. Do this for every `IF()` that contains a query, and I am ready to bet you are going to speed up your query by several orders of magnitude.

There is a lot more to say about your current code. Unfortunately, you will probably need to refactor some parts of your ORM. Add new, more specialised methods to some classes, and make them use new queries that you crafted manually. Then refactor your current operation so that it uses these new methods.